# ASP.NET MVC - Change tabs AJAX RenderAction

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm Spanish so my English is bad. I hope my next explanation is clear.

In this moment I have this code:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    <div id="table-ser1">
        @{Html.RenderAction("Name", "Name2", new {ser ="ser1", s1 = s1, s2 = s2});}
    </div>
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">
    <div id="table-ser2">
        @{Html.RenderAction("Name", "Name2", new {ser ="ser2", s1 = s1, s2 = s2});}
    </div>
</div>
```

The fact is that, in this moment, when the page is loaded, al the content is loaded and the page is very slow. How can I change this with AJAX? I want that when the page is loaded it only has the content of the first tab loaded and when the second tab is clicked, it loads the content of that tab.

Finnally, if I return to the first tab, it has to be loaded because of the first time and it doesn't have to loaded it again.

Thank you!

Comment: Well that's quite possible if you give more details. Are you using jquery-ui tabs or some other?? and what are those `s1=s1`,`s2=s2`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao `s1=s1` are parameters to the mvc action.  It's common to specify the parameter name+value even though it can be left out where the name matches the value variable name `new { ser="ser1",s1, s2}`

Comment: Hello! I think I use JQuery-UI but how can I ensure that? This page was made and I am working now on it.. and all is new for me!

Comment: You see anywhere in js file or view file a code like `$( "#tabs" ).tabs();` If yes then you are using `jquery-ui` and see you have included `jquery-ui.js` anywhere.

Comment: Yes! They are both!! Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

[jquery ui tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax) has an option for that out of the box (see link).

However, there were some issues with the ajax loading and, a quick look at the above link, shows there are still some issues (eg it showed tab 4 when I clicked tab1 then 3 quickly and 3 (the ajax one) always reloads).

I recommend you look at the [beforeActivate](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate) event (or similar)

Set each tab so that it knows if it's loaded or not and load when it's activated.

Use a simple `$.ajax` call or `$("#div").load(...)` to get the content, eg:

```
$("#table-ser2").load("@Url.Action("Name", "Name", ... ");
```